# Overflow ethers

Tags: ethers.js

I am using ethers.js and not sure why this is returning an overflow error.

```
const data = {
  price: ethers.utils.parseEther("2.0") * 
}
```

error

Unhandled Rejection (Error): overflow [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NUMERIC_FAULT-overflow ] (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=12000000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

This statement works fine on my end?

`ethers.utils.parseEther("2.0");`

Does it also look like you might not have the entire code example posted here?

Comment: the issue was that i was multiply by another integer . I had to convert it to a bigNumber

Comment: yeah that makes sense